# Accessing files located on a Windows drive from OS X via Parallels is very slow

Tags: macos, mac, windows-8.1, filesystems, parallels

I have Visual Studio 2013 running in Windows 8.1 in Parallels on OS X. I prefer to use text editors on the OS X side. The project files are stored on the Windows drive.

Before I had them on the OS X drive which was accessible in Windows as a network drive. Unfortunately, Windows cannot detect file changes on a network drive so I had to move the files to the Windows C: drive. This helped with Visual Studio picking up on the changes made in Sublime Text for Mac but introduced this new issue of sporadic freezing while accessing files (opening, saving, moving). These simple operations may take up to a few minutes instead of mere seconds with this setup.

Any ideas on how to configure this to be snappy or at least not so excruciatingly slow?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the windows 8.1 virtual drive is the culprit.
Typically, whenever you virtualize an environment, you have some overhead to deal with(which will slow down the speed of saving and reading files from within a virtual environment like Parrallels). What little information I was able to find on the web indicates that Parrallels doesn't offer any type of disk access beyond installing to the virtual drive(in your case, you've created a windows 8 Guest system which I imagine is running NTFS on a virtual hard disk created in Parrallels). There is some discussion of using bootcamp. See the link for specifics. http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v5/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/23580.htm

In a nut shell, you'll either have to deal with it being slow or you'll have to re-build the guest OS(windows8) using the bootcamp process described in the link. True raw access to a sata drive in a mac will be faster than a virtualized drive created in parrallels.

Also, a more obvious item to check would be software updates for the mac and for parrallels. Something may have been patched recently. Contact parrallels directly. They wrote the software, they would best know what internal mechanisms are used to write data to their virtual drives.